# Generic factory parameters in Typescript

Tags: generics, typescript

This is the sample from the official Typescript documentation for a generic factory. In this sample the constructor does not take parameters.

```
function create<T>(c: {new(): T; }): T {
  return new c();
}
```

How could I rewrite this so that in addition to a type, the factory method accepts other parameters and passes them when it invokes the constructor of the class it is instantiating? So the return statement would look something like this:

```
return c(p1, p2);
```

Something that wasn't clear to me is that this

```
{new(): T; }
```

is effectively an interface, inasmuch as it defines the terms of assessment for compatibility of a proposed class, incidentally also declaring the constructor signature. I'm going to answer my own question.

Comment: You need to pass the `create` function a class which will then be instantiated.  What are `p1` and `p2`?

Comment: p1 and p2 are arbitrary additional parameters to the factory method that are to be passed to the constructor when it is invoked.

Comment: The function is generic, will it always be called with classes that have a constructor which expects 2 arguments? And what are the types of those arguments?

Comment: @NitzanTomer I have just learnt what the `{new(): T;}` part means and now I think my own question is too broad. I'm going to close it and keep researching. Thank you for trying.

Comment: You can try to explain your problem better in your question, maybe give an example of what you want to have, can be pseudo code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
module Factory {
    export function createInstance<T extends Wibble, K extends IRaw1>(ctor: { new (raw: K): T }, data: K): T {
        return new ctor(data);
    }
}
var raw1 = { Foo: "foo" } as IRaw1;
var d1 = Factory.createInstance(Wibble, raw1);

var raw2 = { Foo: "foo", Bar: "bar" } as IRaw2;
var d2 = Factory.createInstance(Wobble, raw2);
```

If your constructors need more arguments, then just add them to the one object you're passing to the ctor, this way you won't need to add more generic constraints per argument.

Comment: I had this exact same thought this morning (it's 0747 here) while waking up, although constraining with extends is something that hadn't yet occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't define a single factory method that can pass an *arbitrary* number of parameters to the constructor of an arbitrary class.

You can, however, define a factory method for any *specific* number of constructor parameters. [Here's a rather elaborate sample in the Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Wibble%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20raw%3A%20IRaw1%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(raw%3A%20IRaw1)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.raw%20%3D%20raw%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toString()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.raw.Foo%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Wobble%20extends%20Wibble%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(raw%3A%20IRaw2)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(raw)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(raw.Bar)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toString()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(%3CIRaw2%3Ethis.raw).Bar%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IRaw1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IRaw2%20extends%20IRaw1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Amodule%20Factory%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20createInstance%3CT1%2CT2%3E(ctor%3A%20new(p%3A%20T1)%20%3D%3E%20T2%2C%20p%3AT1)%3A%20T2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20ctor(p)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20faultyRaw%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22blart%22%3B%0D%0Avar%20raw%3A%20IRaw2%20%3D%20%3CIRaw2%3E%7B%20Foo%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%20Bar%3A%20%22bar%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0Avar%20d%20%3D%20Factory.createInstance(Wobble%2C%20raw)%3B%0D%0Avar%20e%20%3D%20Factory.createInstance(Wibble%2C%20faultyRaw)%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(d.toString())%3B). 
It defines classes and interfaces and derived classes and interfaces and then uses them to demonstrate the factory method working.

Line 38 of the example is probably the most interesting and impressive part of the whole show: an incompatible parameter is specified *and this is statically detected by the editor!* By implication line 38 has passed the same check, and this matches expectation; Wobble is a derivative of Wibble and therefore acceptable, and the parameter is declared as IRaw2 which is a derivative of the declared parameter type of IRaw1, and therefore also acceptable.

If you wanted a two-parameter constructor it would look like this:

```
export function createInstance<T1, T2, T3>(ctor: new(p: T1, q: T2) => T3, p:T1, q:T2): T3 {
  return new ctor(p, q);
}
```